# How to find backed up key files for ASUS motherboard?

Tags: boot, usb, motherboard, bios

I recently disabled secure boot following the instructions [here](https://www.technorms.com/45538/disable-enable-secure-boot-asus-motherboard-uefi-bios-utility).

The process was simply to plug in a USB stick and backup four key files, I did that and disabled secure boot successfully. However, now when I plug in the USB stick in another computer, I cannot see those four (PK, KEK, DB and DBX) files. Are they supposed to be in the root folder? I checked hidden files/folders too. I cannot find them..

I wanted to further back them up in case I lose the USB stick. Can I somehow re-enable secure boot without these files? Maybe resetting everything? Is there a way for this? Or have I disabled secure boot forever?

TIA,

Comment: Why didn't you just disable Secure Boot?  Why did you remove the key entirely?  All UEFI ASUS motherboards have the ability to disable Secure Boot

Comment: I thought disabling secure boot meant removing (cut-paste'ing) the keys. Well, that's what I understood from those instructions.. :)

Comment: You can just turn it off, you don't have to remove the keys, that's only helpful if you want to replace the keys so you can turn it on and boot other operating systems